# Unable to write to Elasticsearch after deployed to Azure VM

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, azure-vm

I deployed ELK stack in a azure virtual machine that I created following this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-elasticsearch#start-logstash-and-add-data-to-elasticsearch). Inside of my kibana.yml file I added server.host: "0.0.0.0" and inside of my elasticsearch.yml file I did under the network section network.host: 0.0.0.0 and http.port:9200. Then I started both kibana and elasticsearch service. When I go to the public ip address for my vm followed by the port for kibana and ES it works. i.e. xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5601 and xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200.

In the azure portal, in my vm I added an inbound port rule for port 9200 so I can access the ip:9200 and get a result back. Everything works smoothly **the issue I am facing** is that on my MVC project, I used to have "localhost:9200" for elasticsearch when writing logs to ES. I replaced that with the VM ip so it would no longer be localhost.

After running the mvc project, it should write the logs to the vm ip address elasticsearch. I go to the vm ip:5601 and try to create an index pattern for the mvc, it does not give me the name of the index's that were created.

Is there like a firewall setting or a port rule I need to include to allow my ip address to communicate with the vm ip for this to work?

Comment: take a look at the `_cat/indices?v` API. if there's nothing there you need to confirm your app is indeed sending things to Elasticsearch successfully

Comment: Where can I do that? @MarkWalkom

Comment: it's an API endpoint, you'd usually call that from Dev Tools in Kibana. but you can use postman or curl or something